# How to convert contents of a hidden webview to uiimage?

Tags: iphone, ipad

In my application, I converted the contents loaded in a UIWebView to a UIImage and had shown it in an UIImageView.

Now what I want to do is have a hidden webview load contents from an URL, and then convert its contents into a UIImage.

Can any body please suggest a method?

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourWebView.bounds.size);
[yourWebView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```